# DependencyProperty in Windows Runtime, XAML values appear empty

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, dependency-properties

I have a simple UserControl in a XAML Windows RT app. The DependencyProperty appears to be set just fine, and breakpoints in the code show the target property of 'TwitterMessage' gets the correct object at runtime, after the 'IsLoaded' event. The problem is, the binding values inside the UserControl's child controls are empty when the XAML is rendered. It's like its ignoring the values of the TwitterMessage property. Any ideas? Intellisense seems to think I'm doing it right as it autocompletes the bindings in the markup.

The Usercontrol is given a simple invocation like so:

```
<local:TwitterMessageUserControl TwitterMessage="{Binding Message}" Grid.Column="2" />
```

UserControl Markup is as follows:

```
<UserControl
x:Class="TwitterMessageUserControl"
...
x:Name="root">

<Border Height="85" Width="400" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource ApplicationSecondaryForegroundThemeBrush}" BorderThickness="1" >

    <StackPanel Background="{ThemeResource AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrush}" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="73" x:Name="Avatar" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="73" Margin="10,5,0,0" Source="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=TwitterMessage.Tweet.AuthorAvatarUrl}"/>
        <StackPanel Margin="15,0,0,0">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="TweetText" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=TwitterMessage.Tweet.Message, Mode=OneWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="Black" Width="300" Margin="0,10,0,0" FontSize="12"/>
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="— @someone via Twitter" x:Name="TweetFromText" Foreground="Black" Margin="0,5,0,0"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

And codebehind is as follows:

```
public sealed partial class TwitterMessageUserControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TwitterMessageProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("TwitterMessage", typeof(TweetMessage), typeof(TwitterMessageUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public TweetMessage TwitterMessage
    {
        get { return (TweetMessage)GetValue(TwitterMessageProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TwitterMessageProperty, value); }
    }

    public TwitterMessageUserControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += TwitterMessageUserControl_Loaded;
    }

    void TwitterMessageUserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recreated the app quickly. When running the app I noticed this error in the debug output:

> Error: BindingExpression path error: 'Message' property not found on
>   'App4.TwitterMessageUserControl'. BindingExpression: Path='Message'
>   DataItem='App4.TwitterMessageUserControl'; target element is
>   'App4.TwitterMessageUserControl' (Name='root'); target property is
>   'TwitterMessage' (type 'TweetMessage')

The problem is that when you do `DataContext = this;` in the `TwitterMessageUserControl_Loaded` it will look for a `Message` property on itself instead of the DataContext set in your view. Comment out this line and it should work fine:

[image]

Additionally if you want to simplify the bindings further in the `UserControl` XAML you can bind to the `root` in the Border, and then just bind without specifying the `ElementName` for every binding inside that, like this:

```
<Border DataContext="{Binding ElementName=root}" Height="85" Width="400" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource ApplicationSecondaryForegroundThemeBrush}" BorderThickness="1" >
    <StackPanel Background="{ThemeResource AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrush}" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="73" x:Name="Avatar" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="73" Margin="10,5,0,0" Source="{Binding TwitterMessage.Tweet.AuthorAvatarUrl}"/>
        <StackPanel Margin="15,0,0,0">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="TweetText" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding TwitterMessage.Tweet.Message}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="Black" Width="300" Margin="0,10,0,0" FontSize="12"/>
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="— @someone via Twitter" x:Name="TweetFromText" Foreground="Black" Margin="0,5,0,0"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will check this out when I get home. Did you mean "comment out" and not "uncomment out" the DataContext = this; line? Also, I should have clarified, that TwitterMessage is inherited from Message; and technically I am passing an item from a List<Message> into the binding. When I go into the debug reflector I see the TwitterMessage type just fine, but I wonder if the DependencyProperty needs to be type Message? Again, I'll try to remove the datacontext line tonight and see what happens.

Comment: Yes, remove the line "DataContext = this;". Regarding the binding I would need to see the model you use as DataContext for the view. But because you said the DependencyProperty TwitterMessage gets the correct value at runtime it should Work fine.

Comment: You sir are right on the money. I appreciate the help and will award the bounty as soon as it will let me.